# Moving average query MS Access

Tags: ms-access, subquery, moving-average

I am trying to calculate the moving average of my data. I have googled and found many examples on this site and others but am still stumped. I need to calculate the average of the previous 5 flow for the record selected for the specific product.

My Table looks like the following:

```
TMDT                  Prod  Flow
8/21/2017 12:01:00 AM  A    100
8/20/2017 11:30:45 PM  A    150
8/20/2017 10:00:15 PM  A    200
8/19/2017 5:00:00  AM  B    600
8/17/2017 12:00:00 AM  A    300
8/16/2017 11:00:00 AM  A    200
8/15/2017 10:00:31 AM  A    50
```

I have been trying the following query:

```
SELECT b.TMDT, b.Flow, (SELECT AVG(Flow) as MovingAVG
  FROM(SELECT TOP 5 * 
  FROM [mytable] a
  WHERE Prod="A" AND [a.TMDT]< b.TMDT
    ORDER BY a.TMDT DESC)) 
  FROM mytable AS b;
```

When I try to run this query I get an input prompt for b.TMDT. Why is b.TMDT not being pulled from mytable?

Should I be using a different method altogether to calculate my moving averages?

I would like to add that I started with another method that works but is extremely slow. It runs fast enough for tables with 100 records or less. However, if the table has more than 100 records it feels like the query comes to a screeching halt.

Original method below.
I created two queries for each product code (There are 15 products): Q_ProdA_Rank and Q_ProdA_MovAvg

Q_ProdA_RanK (T_ProdA is a table with Product A's information):

```
SELECT a.TMDT, a.Flow, (Select count(*) from [T_ProdA] 
where TMDT<=a.TMDT) AS Rank
FROM [T_ProdA] AS a
ORDER BY a.TMDT DESC;
```

Q_ProdA_MovAvg

```
SELECT b.TMDT, b.Flow, Round((Select sum(Flow) from [Q_PRodA_Rank] where 
Rank between b.Rank-1 and (b.Rank-5))/IIf([Rank]<5,Rank-1,5),0) AS 
MovingAvg
FROM [Q_ProdA_Rank] AS b;
```

Comment: Why doesn't date/time have year?

Comment: I forgot to type it. It does have the year. The format is actually mm/dd/yyyy mm:hh:ss am/pm

Comment: I give up. If it is possible to calc rolling TOP 5 over date range and by group in Access, beyond my knowledge level. I would probably go with VBA. I can get the TOP 5 per prod and calculate average on that dataset but can't get the 'rolling' output.

Comment: It is possible to get the rolling average by joining the table to itself on the condition that x.prod = y.prod AND x.tmdt >= y.tmdt, and ranking the rows using DCOUNT, then averaging only the rows with rank of <5.

However, if your table is at all large, you will see some pretty massive performance hits.  If you have a primary key, and the records were inserted sequentially (that is, the dates would have the same order as the ids), then you could avoid the DCOUNT, but you would still have the performance problem of the self join.

How big is the table, and is there a key?

Comment: The table currently has 5200 records. It will continue to grow most likely it will have ~15K records. I am assuming this will be a year's worth of data. There is a primary key. The PK is composed with 5 fields.

Comment: @BarbieShaw: sorry, I didn't see that you had replied.  You've probably moved on, but I'll try to put together something tonight that uses a couple of different solutions.  If your database isn't sensitive, it would save me some time if you attached it.  If it isn't, I'll just dummy something up.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're using a nested subquery, and as far as I know (can't find the right site for the documentation at the moment), variable scope in subqueries is limited to the direct parent of the subquery. This means that for your nested query, b.TMDT is outside of the variable scope.

Edit: As this is an interesting problem, and a properly-asked question, here is the full SQL answer. It's somewhat more complex than your try, but should run more efficiently

It contains a nested subquery that first lists the 5 previous flows for per TMDT and prod, then averages that, and then joins that in with the actual query.

```
SELECT A.TMDT, A.Prod, B.MovingAverage
FROM MyTable AS A LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT JoinKeys.TMDT, JoinKeys.Prod, Avg(Top5.Flow) As MovingAverage 
    FROM (
            SELECT JoinKeys.TMDT, JoinKeys.Prod, Top5.Flow
            FROM MyTable As JoinKeys INNER JOIN MyTable AS Top5 ON JoinKeys.Prod = Top5.Prod
            WHERE Top5.TMDT In (
                SELECT TOP 5 A.TMDT FROM MyTable As A WHERE JoinKeys.Prod = A.Prod AND A.TMDT < JoinKeys.TMDT ORDER BY A.TMDT
            )
        )
    GROUP BY JoinKeys.TMDT, JoinKeys.Prod
) AS B
ON A.Prod = B.JoinKeys.Prod AND A.TMDT = B.JoinKeys.TMDT
```

While in my previous version I advocated a VBA approach, this is probably more efficient, only more difficult to write and adjust.