# MS Access Query: How to calculate the largest sum of 3 continuous records by unique group?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to write a query in MS Access/SQL that will provide me with the largest sum of any 3 continuous records in the table (calculated by group). An example of what I'm aiming to do is shown in the picture below:

[image]

Any help with achieving the desired output would be GREATLY appreciated :)

Cheers,

Grant

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) to understand why

Comment: How 2 cumulative add to 1750 ?

Comment: That was a mistake it should be 1700 not 1750

Comment: Why it should not 1500 ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45824087/moving-average-query-ms-access/45825801#45825801 for how to calculate a moving average, this can easily be adjusted to a sum by removing the `TOP` clause and using `SUM` instead of `AVG`

Comment: Md. Suman... 1500 is the sum of just the first 3 months for ID = 2 (Feb to Apr 2012). If you look at the next possible 3 month sum (Mar-May) for ID =2 you will see that it is larger since 1700 = 600+500+600

Comment: Why you remove my edit?

Comment: Not sure what you mean

Comment: Check Now the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try a triple join

```
 SELECT t1.unique_id, MAX(t1.production + t2.production + t3.production)
 FROM yourTable t1
 JOIN yourTable t2
   ON t1.Date = DateAdd("m", -1, t2.Date)
  AND t1.unique_id = t2.unique_id 
 JOIN yourTable t3
   ON t1.Date = DateAdd("m", -2, t3.Date)
  AND t1.unique_id = t3.unique_id 
 GROUP BY t1.unique_id
```

EDIT: Better use LEFT JOIN

```
 SELECT t1.unique_id, MAX(   t1.production + 
                          Nz(t2.production,0) + 
                          Nz(t3.production,0) ) as three_months
 FROM yourTable t1
 LEFT JOIN yourTable t2
   ON t1.Date = DateAdd("m", -1, t2.Date)
  AND t1.unique_id = t2.unique_id 
 LEFT JOIN yourTable t3
   ON t1.Date = DateAdd("m", -2, t3.Date)
  AND t1.unique_id = t3.unique_id 
 GROUP BY t1.unique_id
```

Comment: The only problem with this solution is in the case of 1 or 2 months that don't have records from the preceding months. In this case, because you used inner joins, this query will result in those months not being considered. You can fix this by changing the joins to left joins and wrapping t2.production and t3.production in the select list with calls to the NZ() function.

Comment: @NathanM. Good Catch but still I like the `JOIN` before the sub query.

Comment: Agreed. In general, joins are superior to sub-queries. Under normal circumstances, I'd rewrite my query as a join, but I'm going to leave it as is since the sub-query approach can be resolved in Design View. If my primary concern was performance, I'd go with your approach.

Comment: BTW @NathanM The only problem is if OP have only 1 or 2 months in the DB. Otherwise I look for months ahead not behind. So In this case `JUL-11` is already include it on `MAY-JUN-JUL` group.

Comment: Very good point. I didn't think about those cases being included in ones below. So, what I said is only a problem if there are less than 3 months in the table, in which case the query would be trivial/pointless anyways.

Comment: @NathanM. Still  I  edit my question to include the `LEFT JOIN` version 
in case of new unique_id enter the db.

Comment: Stupid question but do I need to first create new tables to make this query work or should I be able to just paste that code into my SQL View editor without adding any extra tables?

Comment: This use your existing table I just use alias t1, t2, t3 to reference the same table

Comment: I typed this in my SQL Editor (except obviously with the correct table name & field name references) but I'm getting a syntax error.. It says >> Syntax Error (missing operator) in query expression '' , <<. Then it highlights the -1, which is written inside the "DateAdd" function line

Comment: sorry I dont have `access`, I just use google to get the `DateAdd` syntax. You should try with a smaller example to see if can make it work.

Answer (score 0):

This solution requires 1 other piece of information: how to reliably order the records. For simplicity, I would typically go with an integer column. In this case, I'm going to assume that that the date is stored as the "Date/Time" datatype and that there are no gaps between months. If that is the case, then the following should work:

```
SELECT T1.UNIQUE_ID
       ,MAX(T1.Production
            + Nz((SELECT T2.Production
                    FROM MyTable AS T2
                   WHERE T2.UNIQUE_ID = T1.UNIQUE_ID
                         AND T2.Date = DateAdd("m", -1, T1.Date), 0)
            + Nz((SELECT T2.Production
                    FROM MyTable AS T2
                   WHERE T2.UNIQUE_ID = T1.UNIQUE_ID
                         AND T2.Date = DateAdd("m", -2, T1.Date), 0) AS Max_3_Month_Cumulative
  FROM MyTable AS T1
 GROUP BY T1.UNIQUE_ID
```

As a side note, this query can be resolved in Design View.